# A stream method for all activities

Tags: getstream-io

I'm using stream-laravel to add the stream in but I see that it configured to use user. So how could I go about using the method to read every single activity on the site?

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly common and easy to make use of a separate global feed alongside all the unique topic or user feeds in an app.

When adding activities to a feed, there is an optional parameter to instruct Stream that the activity should also be copied to one or more other feeds. See "[Targeting Using the "TO" Field](https://getstream.io/docs/php/#targetting)" in the docs.

The stream-laraval library supports this via a hook on the Eloquent parent model: `ActivityTrait.activityNotify()`. Just return a single-time array containing the name of your global feed.

```
class MyActivity extends Eloquent {
  use GetStream\StreamLaravel\Eloquent\ActivityTrait;

public function activityNotify()
{
  return array('global_feed');
}
```

If you're looking for other examples, there is also section on "notifications" in the [README.md](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-laravel/). In that case there are individual notification feeds for each user and they're obtained via `FeedManager.getNotificationFeed()`. So you've got some flexibility there.